# How to access url project in server by public?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

When the url like this : http://31.******.75/lap***gar/, the result : https://postimg.org/image/fywttv7op/

When the url like this : http://31.******.75/lap***gar/public/, the result : https://postimg.org/image/ddzh73rqp/

I see there is no data and no error

Note :

- I had add file .env
- I try check the error in log (\storage\logs\laravel.log), but I don't find the file laravel.log
- I try in localhost, it's working. The system appears. But I try in server, the system no appears

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Is your storage folder (and its subfolders) writable?

Comment: Your web server should have the `/public` folder as document root. And you should also disable directory list on your web server. If you're using Apache and haven't turned directory listing, it will show all files in the folder instead, if it doesn't find any index file.

Comment: I still do not understand. I update my question

Comment: Along with Magnus' suggestion, look at the server logs if you have access to them. They'd be in a subfolder in `/var/log/`

Comment: If this is a shared hosting account, and you want to upload your project, you need to tinker a bit with the .htaccess file. and point it to your index.php that's inside the public folder. you can also do it with a workaround(not recommended, but it works), is to move the public folder to your root and in your bootstrap just point it to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all : Cmon man please take care on what you are posting, the images you gave are not correctly obfuscated, so we can easily take note that the full URL of your project is `http://31.220.56.75/laplakgar/` ... we can also know you are using apache2 for ubuntu because of the `http://31.220.56.75/` let as it.

Now, if your question is how to define your server document root to `/laplakgar/public/` the answer is in your `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` or `httpd.conf`

Then when you go to `http://31.220.56.75/` you will have the content of `http://31.220.56.75/laplakgar/public/`

Find the `DocumentRoot /var/www` to `/var/www/laplakgar/public` (also depends of your installation, but it should be the path of your public directory)

Some infos about the DocumentRoot instruction : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: How do you know the name of my project is laplakgar? Even though I had crossed out it name

Comment: As I just said, you didn't obfuscated it everywhere. Check your first picture `Index of laplakgar`